# apply_sync is as same speed as serial

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that takes 128ms on the CPU, I tried to paralleize it, but it has the same effect, no speed up at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

This is the function that is computionaly expensive:

```
def compute(id, x,y,frame_id,df_region, region_buffered, df_line):
    gb = ('trajectory_id',)
    global general_pd
    general_pd.loc[len(general_pd)] = [id, x,y, frame_id]
    grouped = general_pd.loc[general_pd['trajectory_id'] == id]


    rpp = RawParameterProcessor(grouped, df_line, frame_idx, df_region, region_buffered,  gb=gb, v_thresh=5 / 3.6)

    df_parameter_car = rpp.compute()

    return df_parameter_car
```

and I'm using it in tensorflow object detection where I perform compution on the detected objects:

Note that the following piece of code is executed in the main loop, where I get that data from a cv2 video capture.

### FOR EACH FRAME FROM VIDEO CAPTURE

```
for trk in car_detections:
    trk = trk.astype(np.int32)
    p = np.array([[((trk[1] + trk[3]) / 2,  (trk[0] + trk[2]) / 2)]], dtype=np.float32)
    center_pt = cv2.perspectiveTransform(p, H)
    ptx = center_pt.T.item(0)
    pty = center_pt.T.item(1)
    df_cars = pool.apply_async(compute, (trk[4], ptx, pty, frame_idx, df_region, region_buffered, df_line,))
    results.append(df_cars)
    for result in results:
        genera_data_pd_cars = genera_data_pd_cars.append(result.get())
```

Comment: [The examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) say that `# launching multiple evaluations asynchronously *may* use more processes`

Comment: @wwii so there is no solution ?

Comment: You may want to use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) with the `ProcessPoolExecutor`. `concurrent.futures` is pretty nice, it handles all the behind-the-scenes activity of distributing arguments to functions in multiple processes and retrieving the results.  The examples are pretty easy to adapt.

Comment: I like to use the format of the example given for the `ThreadPoolExecutor` : submitting multiple tasks in a loop and gathering the futures then iterating over the futures as they complete to get the results. Although other ways also work pretty good.  Realize there is a time cost for setting it all up and transporting objects to and from the processes - YMMV depending on the actual cpu load or execution time of the task.

Comment: pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(14)
 still the same speed, very slow

Comment: How long, typically, does it take to run `compute` once?

Comment: 128ms to take for a one frame

Comment: @wwii No soultion ? I really don't know what's wrong, it's driving me crazy

Comment: What I noticed is done is always false
            df_peds = pool.submit(compute,other[4], ptx, pty, frame_idx, df_region, region_buffered, df_line)
            print(df_peds.done())

Comment: One cost when using multiprocessing is that the arguments/data need to be [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to send them to the *child* process.  The nature of the objects may make pickling time consuming and sending all the data back and forth between processes takes time.

Comment: @wwii Do you know how to modify the code to make it picklable ?

Comment: I just have the arguments, numpy, and pandas dataframe, and they are picklable

Comment: ```df_peds = pool.submit(compute, trk[4], ptx, pty, frame_idx, df_region.to_pickle('df_region.pkl'),
                                  region_buffered,
                                  df_line.to_pickle('df_line.pkl'))```
same issue very slow

Comment: I can't find a solution please help

Comment: One last comment - and I am just guessing. Your function execution is in a loop and being processed sequentially even though you are submitting it to a separate process. Maybe take the function out of the loop. Accumulate many sets of arguments then execute the function in parallel for those accumulated arguments. Similar to the example in the [multiprocessing introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) using pool.map().

Comment: @wwii I did what you suggested, similar performance